# How is line 2 is evaluated?

Tags: java-8, assignment-operator, post-increment

```
int f = 1;
f = f++;
System.out.println(f);
```

post increment operator is having a higher precedence than assignment operator so 
i suppose value of f (that is 1) is used for assignment and f is incremented then the output would be 2 (as value of f is now 2)
but the output is 1, but how? where am i wrong?

my explanation results in right answer in the code below

```
int f = 1;
int g = f++;
System.out.println(f);
```

output is 2 in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't assign a value to a variable before you evaluate the value. Hence you must evaluate `f++` first. And since `f++` returns 1, that's the value assigned to `f`, which overwrites the incremented value of `f`.

Your second snippet is a completely different scenario, since you assign the value of `f++` to a different variable, so the incremented value of `f` is not overwritten.

Comment: To get output 2 @Jilson need to put pre increment like f = ++f; am i right ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha that would work, since `++f` will return 2. Of course, there's no reason to assign the value of either `++f` or `f++` back to `f`.

Comment: There seems to be a common misunderstanding what “higher precedence” means. Actually, the OP is right in that the post increment operator has a higher precedence than assignment operator. but that just means that it is evaluated *before* the assignment, so the subsequent assignment cancels its side effect. The OP seems to assume that the increment will happen after the assignment, but that would contradict the precedence rule.